# URL will not load in frameset using IE8

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

We are currently using VBulletin 3.6 which loads public pages in iframes within the admin (eg. member profile, who's logged in, etc.).

We've recently completed a redesign of our site and for some reason IE8 in compatability or non-compatability mode will no longer load the public website within the admin via iframes.  The admin works fine in firefox and chrome.

Here's a stripped down version of the code which loads our public website in an iframe.  It works fine in Firefox, but I can't for the life of me get it working in IE8. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<title>IFRAME Test</title>
</head>

<frameset framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
    <frame src="http://www.cardschat.com" name="nav" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="no" />
    </frameset>
<noframes>
    <body>
        <p>Your browser does not support frames. Please get one that does!</p>
    </body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. The problem seems to be caused by the website you are referencing (http://www.cardschat.com). Maybe they have a script that blocks this kind of requests.

Comment: I assume that there is an issue with the code in the site being loaded, but I can't identify exactly what code is causing it.  As stated this works fine in firefox and only an issue in IE8.  Could it be an IE8 security/content blocking issue?

Comment: There is a lot of browser-specific code in your scripts, so I can't figure out what is the problem right now. Why are you using frames anyway?

Comment: It's not my choice, it's how VBulletin's admin works :( and I don't want to re-code the VB admin interface.

Comment: If you want, you can try to remove all scripts on the website (all .js AND embedded scripts) to see if the problem is really caused by Javascript. If yes, reinsert them one by one until you find the faulty one. If not, then let us know! It's probably a problem with the server configuration then.

Answer (score 0):

Is there X-Frame-Options option in the header received? If so, iframe will not load content.

More information at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header